# Re-expressing a function in terms of an unknown constant

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

This is a pretty elementary question perhaps, but one I'm just not sure I'm understanding. Imagine I have some unknown $n$, and I'm told $3|\big((n+1)^3 - 2n^3\big)$. Because I know 3 divides this, I believe I can re-express $n$ in terms of some other unknown $c$ as $n = 3c +1$ and that works. Now, I got there by educated guesswork so I'd appreciate any pointers on a more rigorous approach!

Instead, imagine I have another unknown constant $k$, and $3k|\big((n+1)^3 - 2n^3\big)$, is there a way to re-express $n$ in terms of another constant $c_{2}$ and $k$, analogous to the trial-and-error solution for the constant case? Guessing again, I'd say $n = k(3c_{1} +1)$ but is this right or unique? I'm not even quite sure what you'd call this but open to learning!

Comment: Not sure to understand what you ask, but $a|b$ is equivalent to "there exists $k$ such that $b=ak$".

Comment: Hint: $\ 3\mid n \iff n\equiv 0\pmod{\!3}.\,$ By little Fermat $\,x^3\equiv x\pmod{\!3}\,$ hence
$$\begin{align} 3\ \mid\, &\,(n\!+\!1)^3-2n^3\\  \iff \bmod 3\!:\,\ 0\equiv &\,(n\!+\!1)^3-2n^3\\ \equiv &\,(n\!+\!1)\,-\,2n\\  \equiv &\,\ n-1\\  \iff\quad 3\,\ \mid &\,\ n-1 \end{align}\qquad$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rigorous approach for your first example. We are given that $3 | [(n + 1)^3 - 2n^3]$, i.e. that $3 | -(n^3 - 3 n^2 - 3 n - 1)$.
Given that 3 divides the whole expression, and that $3 \mid (-3n^2 - 3n)$, we can conclude that $3$ divides $n^3 - 1$. And as 3 is prime, this means either $3 \mid (n - 1)$ or $3 \mid (n^2 + n + 1)$.

If the first case holds, we can write $3c = n - 1$ or $n = 3c + 1$ as you noted.

If the first case doesn't hold, then we must have $3 | n^2 + n + 1$. Also, we know either $n \equiv 0\ (3)$ or $n \equiv 2\ (3)$. However, if $n \equiv 0$ then $n^2 + n + 1 \equiv 1\ (3)$, contradicting that $3 | n^2 + n + 1$. Similarly, if $n \equiv 2$ then $n^2 + n + 1 \equiv 1\ (3)$, giving the same contradiction. Therefore the first case holds and we can rewrite $n = 3c + 1$.

Comment: Since you resort to a case analysis, i.e. brute-force checking all root possibilities $\,n\equiv 0,1,2\pmod{3},\,$  there is no need for the first paragraph, i.e. simply test which are roots $\!\bmod 3\,$ of $\,(n+1)^2-2n^3\ \ $

Comment: Fair point! I didn't know how else to proceed from the "suppose then $3 | n^2 + n + 1$..." stage, which is why cases appeared late in the game.